# Python GAE - Call to Big Query API throws Deadline exceeded error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've been using the Big Query api and 90% of my requests failed due to  this error:

```
HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/poorproject/queries?alt=json
```

I'm performing UPDATE operation so I'm using the standard SQL instead of legacy SQL. I know that standard SQL is much slower and for this reason the Deadline error is being thrown.

I'm using GAE Endpoints API and I've tried to increase the  [urlfetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051628/gae-appengine-deadlineexceedederror-deadline-exceeded-while-waiting-for-htt)  time but it didn't work.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: I think the default urlfetch time is 60 seconds in the app engine. this problem has been asked so many times but there are no clear documentation provided by google regarding exceeding the urlfetch time.

Comment: Hello @Bravin, yeah I've read about the 60 seconds urlfetch time, but what is really weird is that after maybe 8-10 seconds this error is thrown as well... So I'm kinda lost at this point.. but thanks for your info.

Comment: This has been working for me: urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(600)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about your scenario (e.g. which specific API you are trying to call), I can only speculate as to the possible causes. I suspect you are using the synchronous ['Jobs.Query'](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) API instead of asynchronous ['Jobs.Insert'](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) API. If so, I'd recommend using the asynchronous API since that'd help you avoid any short deadlines on your side since inserting a job is pretty fast. If you are still experiencing timeouts, filing a bug on the BigQuery issue tracker with more details is an option.